# plotting specific points within a spreadsheet in r

Tags: r, plot

currently I am plotting 2000 some lines on a single plot in r. I am using the data from a spreadsheet which i cannot disclose due to sensitive information, but I'll try to illistrate how it is arranged.

```
x1/x1/x1/x1/x1/x1/etc.
y1/y1/y1/y1/y1/y1/etc.
x2/x2/x2/x2/x2/x2/etc.
y2/y2/y2/y2/y2/y2/etc.
...
x4436/x4436/x4436/etc.
y4436/y4436/y4436/etc.
```

where each x1,y1 is a point on a separate line.  I need to plot a point on the endpoint of each line and I cannot seem to get my code to work. Currently I am using this to generate the points:

```
    for (k in (1:2218)*2) {
    q <- unlist(e_web_clear[2*k])
    w <- unlist(e_web_clear[716])
    points(w, q, col = "lightblue")
    }
```

the way I imagined it, it would loop back to each point in every other row, to get only the y value for each line, and it would take the values from only the last column of my data (column 716).

needless to say, it did not work as intended, any suggestions?

EDIT:

spreadsheet with just a small portion of values [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Av6eeDLr2euCdDRfYldhOXVXLXl0TnN1TUZBeVZ6dnc&usp=sharing)

and the code used to generate the lines:

```
     for (j in (1:2218)*2) {
     x <- unlist(e_web_clear[2*j-1,])
     y <- unlist(e_web_clear[2*j,])
     lines(x,y,'l',lwd=.00000000001, col="black")
     }
```

data was imported as text file

Edit2:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abhLM.jpg) is the graph i am getting.

the graph i want to get would have the endpoint of each line highlighted in light blue. i believe it should look something like this. http: / /imgur.com/13b9MZL

Comment: I don't quite follow: the data frame is just two columns of x,y pairs?  And you want to plot a point on the end of the line, but how are the lines defined?  For instance, if it's just x,y pairs, are you plotting from point 1 (in row 1) to point 2, then 2, to 3, etc to create line segments?

Comment: No chance to get a useful solution without data. How did you get the data from the spreadsheet? At least print a str(of your spreadsheet data).

Comment: So you're plotting w/ x,y values in paired rows. OK. Now you need to show us the graph you get and explain the graph you want to get.  BTW, that `lwd` value is silly.  Do you really have a device that plots different lines for 0.00000000001 vs 0.0000001 ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft i have a 7.5k dpi laser printer. with how many lines i have i need as fine of lines as i can, and doing this is easier than calculating the exact value my printer can handle.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

I edited my line loop to place a point on the last vector point of each line.

```
 for (j in (1:2218)*2) {
 x <- unlist(e_web_clear[2*j-1,])
 y <- unlist(e_web_clear[2*j,])
 lines(x,y,'l',lwd=.00000000001, col="black")
 points(x[358], y[358], lwd = 1.5, cex = .1, col = "lightblue")
 }
```